# file transfer to multiple sockets simultaneously

Tags: perl, sockets

In perl, is there a way to broadcast a file from a server socket to multiple client sockets? I want to transfer a single file to multiple systems in least amount of time.

Thanks,
Akshey

Comment: do you want to minimize bandwidth? Are they all on the same subnet? "multiple systems" as in 10 or 10 000 ? :)

Comment: I mean 12 systems on the same subnet. I want to minimize the transmission time.

Answer (score 2):

Over what sort of network?  [IP multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast) is generally usable over a LAN, but not really supported over the Internet.

Note that multicast requires special software for both client & server.  You probably don't want to write your own; there are some implementations linked from the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly set something up with UDP, sending packets willy-nilly.  But that seems self-defeating, because you'd have to make up for lost packets.

I would just do each separately in pretty much the normal way.  You could start a separate execution thread or fork for each recipient though, so that they ran in parallel.